# Make 3 input fields instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, spectrumjs

I implemented [Spectrum Color Picker](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/). There are a couple slight changes I want to make.

- I want to have rgb colors in 3 different input fields.
- I want to have hex color in another input field.
- I want to have name color (ex. red, brown etc.) in another input field.

I want to edit the [source file](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js).

[JavaScirpt Source](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js)

[CSS Source](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.css)

Comment: Is this a question or are you just asking someone to build this for you?

Comment: http://www.freelancer.com/hire/Developer‎

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to customize the library.

Check out the options. Something similar can be found in the below links.

[input[type=color]](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/?color=%23ff8040&color2=%238080c0&color3=%23000000#modes-input)

[Color](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/?color=%23ff8040&color2=%238080c0&color3=%23000000#options-color)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how can I add it under the color picker?